# How to limit the user from typing in more than three integers into the console?

Tags: java, input, keyboard

I want the user to only be able to type in no more than three number into the console. Is there any way to limit or stop the console from accepting keyboard input?

Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Numbers { 
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Type three integers ");
  int firstInt = userInput.nextInt();
  int secondInt = userInput.nextInt();
  int thirdInt = userInput.nextInt();
  System.out.println(firstInt + secondInt + thirdInt);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Before asking for help, please show us what you have attempted.

Comment: ok I did not know. Sorry. I just wanted to understand.

Comment: Maybe at least show some code on what you have tried?

Comment: I updated the code I know it's simple but hey we all had to start somewhere right.

Answer (score -1):

```
 int count = 3;
        Scanner z = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
        while(count>0)
        {
           int n = z.nextInt();
           l.add(n);
           count--;

        }
        Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
```

**Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0)** will allow code to skip next lines in code.

give it a try

Hope this is the solution you are looking for

Comment: Why would the you want to the program to quit the program immediately after three values were read? Presumably they were input for a reason, like maybe to do some calculations with them.

Comment: I updated the code. It's simple and basic I am new to this.